# Como desabilitar um link que está chamando um modal bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Estou tentando fazer um `<a href>` não chamar um modal do [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="md-checkbox-list has-feedback" id="divTermosContrato">
        <div class="md-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" id="chkTermosContrato" name="chkTermosContrato" value="1" class="md-check" disabled="disabled">
          <label for="chkTermosContrato">
             <span></span>
             <span class="check"></span>
             <span class="box"></span> <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#termosContrato" disabled="disabled" tabindex="-1" class="disabled-link">Aceito os termos</a> </label>

        </div>
      </div>
      <span class="erroTermos help-block"> </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div
```

Esse código chama um modal, como desabilitá-lo para que não chame modal ao carregar da página?

Comment: Parece que tem um `data-toggle="modal"` no seu link `a`, tente remover ele e vê se funciona

Comment: mas eu preciso chamar esse modal posteriormente, só preciso desabilita-lo

Comment: Você não pode simplesmente remover o `data-target` por hora e depois colocalo de volta?

Comment: Como fazer isso no Jquery?

Comment: É um código que você não tem acesso? Você ta querendo algum tipo de hack para o link não funcionar por hora então?

Comment: an, não entendi que tu dizer? não, eu to precisando desabilitar ele mesmo

Comment: Tenta o seguinte, com o nome da classe do link você insere o seguinte código jQuery `$('.disabled-link').unbind();` Esse código vai tirar a função de click do link.

Comment: Basicamente o seguinte. O link tem que ficar desabilitado por nativo, quando o usuário selecionar um option, ai sim habilita

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63450/discussion-between-gabrielfalieri-and-ikaro-pinheiro).

Comment: Resolvido, mudei de $("#dtTarget").attr('target', '#termosContrato'); para $("#dtTarget").attr('data-target', '#termosContrato');

Answer (score 0):

O que acontece é que o elemento de ancora - `<a />` - não possui o atributo `disabled`, mas o elemento `<button />` possui este atributo.

Logo, é só trocar o elemento:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#termosContrato" disabled="disabled" tabindex="-1" class="disabled-link">Aceito os termos</a>
```

Por:

```
 <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#termosContrato" disabled="disabled" tabindex="-1" class="disabled-link">Aceito os termos</button>
```